# Android unit tests

Tags: android, юнит-тесты

У меня несколько вопросов.

Допустим, есть у меня есть проект, который находится на стадии тестирования, и тут заказчику захотелось покрыть весь проект тестами. Для себя решил использовать *espresso*, так как более менее знаком с ним. Да и гуглы говорят что покрытие до 95%. Из этого возникают два вопроса.

Первый, как правильно проводить тестирование, я имею ввиду что тестировать, отдельно взятые методы или по функционалу, так как *espresso*, хорошо работает с *ui*.

И второй вопрос, есть методология разработки при помощи *unit* тестов *TDD*, и я с ней знаком, там все понятно, поэтапно, циклично пишутся тесты и разрабатывается проект, но с написание тестов уже к готовому проекту я не сталкивался.

С чего мне начать и как правильно организовать свою работу? Может есть смысл просто покрыть тестами основной функционал, не сильно затрагивая работу отдельных методов?

Answer (score 1):

[Оффициальный туториал от Google](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]